# How to find a recurrence relation for a sequence?

Tags: symbolic, recursion, difference-equations, sequence

I have a sequence given by an explicit formula for n-th term:

```
seq[n_] := FullSimplify[LerchPhi[1/2, 2, -n] - 2^(-2-n) (π^2 - 6 Log[2]^2)/3];
Array[seq, 10]
(* {1, 3/4, 35/72, 11/36, 347/1800, 149/1200, 9701/117600, 209/3675, 8093/198450, 6031/198450} *)
```

I am trying to find a recurrence relation for this sequence (e.g. in a form of [`DifferenceRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) object). An invocation of [`DifferenceRootReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRootReduce.html) does not produce a desired result:

```
DifferenceRootReduce[LerchPhi[1/2, 2, -n] - 2^(-2-n) (π^2 - 6 Log[2]^2)/3, n]
(* LerchPhi[1/2, 2, -n] - 2^(-2-n) (π^2 - 6 Log[2]^2)/3 *)
```

Are there any other ways to find a recurrence relation for a sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/17/01/01/01/0002/):

$$\Phi (z,s,a)=\frac{\Phi (z,s,a-1)-\left((a-1)^2\right)^{-s/2}}{z}$$

First we define two recursive functions:

```
rGexp[0] = -1/4 (Pi^2 - 6 Log[2]^2)/3;
rGexp[n_] := 1/2 rGexp[n - 1]

rlp[0] = LerchPhi[1/2, 2, 0];
rlp[n_] := 1/2 rlp[n + 1] + 1/(n)^2
```

Then we add them:

```
rSeq[n_] := rlp[-n] + rGexp[n]

Simplify@Table[rSeq[n], {n, 1, 10}]

(* {1, 3/4, 35/72, 11/36, 347/1800, 149/1200, 9701/117600, 209/3675, 8093/198450} *)
```

Now, since

```
LerchPhi[1/2, 2, 0]
(* π^2/12 - Log[2]^2/2 *)
```

The above can be reduced to (Thanks to @ybeltukov for noting it!):

```
f[0] = 0
f[n_] := f[n - 1]/2 + 1/n^2
f /@ Range@9
(* {1, 3/4, 35/72, 11/36, 347/1800, 149/1200, 9701/117600, 209/3675, 8093/198450} *)
```

Comment: I'd rather say that I found it by using Mathematics, not Mathematica. Anyway ...

Comment: belisarius, your result is quite simple: `f[0] = 0; f[n_] := f[n - 1]/2 + 1/n^2;` :) May be you add it to the answer?

Comment: @ybeltukov: you're right. But how did you find this simple recurrence relation? We could formulate a modified problem as follows: given a numerical sequence of (say) rational numbers, is there (1) some "NDifferenceRootReduce" to find the recurrence relation or (2) a kind of "RFindFit" for a recurrence relation like f(n) = a f(n-1) + b(n), where a is a numerical parameter to be found and b(n) could be e.g. a polynomial with parameters to be found as well?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I just looked at the belisarius's answer and saw that these two recurrence relations reduced to `f[n_] := f[n - 1]/2 + 1/n^2`. `DifferenceRootReduce` should find this formula, but `LerchPhi` is too difficult for it. For example, it works fine with `Fibonacci[n] + n` (see options [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRootReduce.html)).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze It is interestiong, that `Mathematica` can do it in the opposite way. `RSolve[{f[n] == f[n - 1]/2 + 1/n^2, f[0] == 0}, f[n], n]` gives an equivalent formula with `LerchPhi`.

Comment: @ybeltukov: I'll propose this as an official question.

Comment: @ybeltukov Thanks a lot for noting the nice equivalence :)